# React Native webview won't load ReactJS site

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

Unfortunately I can't share the website in question, I just hope someone can steer me in the right direction without seeing either it or too much of the code.

### The React Native(iOS only) app is built with;

react 16.0.0-alpha.12

react-native 0.47.1

### The website is built with;

React 16.0.0

Babel is set up correctly, and babel-polyfill is baked in too.

### Description

The use-case is that we need to load, say, the FAQs page from the company ReactJS-based site in the mobile phone app's webview component.

However, the webview does not load the bundle.js for the website. CSS, HTML ect loads, but not the React bundle. Running JS inline in a script tag as a test works, but only if I remove the bundle.js file from src.

So something about the ReactJS build does not play nicely when loaded in a RN Webview. The site loads just fine via the mobile phone browsers however.